# Convergence of every third average

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Consider a convergent sequence $(x_n)_{n\geq 1}$ that converges to $x$.
Now consider a new sequence $$y_n =\cases{\frac{x_{n}+x_{n-1}}{2} \text{ if } n \mod 3 = 2\\ x_n \text{ else. }}$$ Does $y_n$ in generell also converge to $x$?

EDIT:
Here is another sequence I am interested in:

Let $x_0 =a, x_n = f(x_{n-1})$ and $(x_n)_{n \geq 0}$ converge to $x$.
Now set $y_0 = x_0$ and for $n \geq 1$,$$y_n = \cases{\frac{y_{n-1}+y_{n-2}}{2} & if $ n \mod 3 = 2$\\ f(y_{n-1}) &\text{ else.}}$$.

Does $y_n$ converge to $x$? I couldn't find any function $f$ for a counterexample.

Comment: yep, it converges to $x$

Comment: (1) $(x_n)$ converges to $x$ by assumption; (2) $(x_{n+1})$ converges to $x$ as a subsequence of $(x_n)$; (3) $(x_n+x_{n+1})$ converges to $2x$ by additivity as the sum of (1) and (2); (4) $\Big(\frac{x_n+x_{n+1}}{2}\Big)$ converges to $x$ by scalar multiplication from (3); (5) $(y_n)$ converges to $x$ because it can be partitioned into 2 (finitely many) sequences (namely (1) and (4)) that both (all) converge to $x$

Comment: Minor correction, in (5) we actually used subsequences of (1) and (4), not (1) and (4) themselves.

Comment: So, a counter-example to the second variant is: $$\cos\Big(\frac{\pi}{x}\Big)^2x^2\Bigg(\cos\Big(\frac{\pi}{x}\Big)^2+\Bigg(\cos\Big(\frac{\pi}{x}\Big)^2-1\Bigg)\Bigg(\frac{-\cos\Big(\frac{\pi}{0.375}\Big)^2+\frac{1}{\cos\Big(\frac{\pi}{0.375}\Big)^2(0.375)^2}}{\cos\Big(\frac{\pi}{0.375}\Big)^2-1}\Bigg)\Bigg)$$ and take $x_0=0.5$

Comment: In this example $(x_n)$ converges to $0$, but $(y_n)$ converges to $1$

Comment: If you had that $|f(x)-f(y)|<|x-y|$ for all $x$ and $y$, the second variant would be true too.

Comment: Wow!! That's interesting. Thanks a lot!!